# Display only images in ListView using ArrayAdapter return black Activity?

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I want add only images to ListView , i created Activity and ArrayAdapter as shown below

**both Activity and ArrayAdapter classes**

```
 public class Main extends ActionBarActivity{
    ListView icons ;
    ArrayList <Drawable> items ;
    Adapter adapter ;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        icons = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.icon);
        items = new ArrayList<Drawable>() { };
        items.add(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.r));
        items.add(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.b));
        items.add(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.g));

        adapter = new Adapter(this,0,items);
        icons.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
class Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<Drawable>{
    ArrayList<Drawable> items ;
    ImageView image ;

    public Adapter(Context c,int resources,ArrayList<Drawable>list){
        super(c,resources,list);
        this.items = list ;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.images, parent, false);
        }
        image= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        image.setBackground(items.get(position));
        return convertView;

    }
}
```

**images.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="350dp"
    android:id="@+id/images" />
```

**main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

what i get is white black Activity , what is wrong with this code ?

thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove second argument from activity's `onCreate`:
use

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //...
}
```

instead of

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
    //...
}
```

Also, you finding wrong ImageView id, replace `R.id.image` with `R.id.images`in Adapter's `getView()`. And change `setBackground()` to `setImageDrawable()`

Answer (score 1):

Change these lines:

```
image= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
image.setBackground(items.get(position));
```

to

```
image= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.images);
image.setImageDrawable(items.get(position));
```

and change

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

to

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
```